# Visual studio code not recognising NPM

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vite

I wanted to make website. And I used Vite to do it (according to tutorial). However Visual studio code is not recognising npm commands (in console).

I have installed nod. js, and have it written in the path. Cmd is recognising npm, and it is giving me the version also.

Do you know where the problem could be?

My code:

```
PS C:\Users\451\Desktop\Web 3.0\client> npm init vite@latest
npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm init vite@latest
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Vite site - https://vitejs.dev

Comment: check following answer from following link https://stackoverflow.com/a/68869632/6018827

Comment: What's the value of `%PATH%`?

Comment: C:\Program Files\nodejs - this is inside path

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Okay so I solved the problem. I don´t know why, but when I used command ***npm -v*** and ***node -v*** inside my visual studio code console it seems to start working. Don´t know why, don´t know how. It just started to work.